# How come I get ClassNotFoundException when backupAgent tries to start

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, android-backup-service

I use the `BackupAgentHelper` to backup the `SharedPreferences` in my Android app. I have tested it in the emulator (Android 1.6 and 2.2) and on my own phone (Android 2.3.3) and it all works well. However, today I got a crash report in the Developer Console looking like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create BackupAgent com.xxx.yyy.MyBackupAgent: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.yyy.MyBackupAgent in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/com.xxx.yyy-2/pkg.apk]
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateBackupAgent(ActivityThread.java:2114)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1138)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.yyy.MyBackupAgent in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/com.xxx.yyy-2/pkg.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateBackupAgent(ActivityThread.java:2064)
... 10 more
```

The backupAgent is declared in the application tag in the Manifest as:

```
android:backupAgent="com.xxx.yyy.MyBackupAgent"
```

Apparantly, the class `MyBackupAgent` *is* present since I can build the `.apk` and it runs just fine on several devices. So how can it be that it does not find the class here? One thing I notice in the message above is that the app seems to be installed in a path which have my package name AND an appended "-2" at the end. Can this cause the classloader to not see the class in my package since I specify the full package name and class in the `android:backupAgent`, or is that part irrelevant? Can anybody understand what the reason can be that the class cannot be found?

Worth to mention is that my app can be installed on SD card.

Excuse me for replacing my real package name with com.xxx.yyy in the message above.

Comment: Just because you can build the APK with the backupAgent listed in the manifest does _not_ mean that it is present. You can put whatever garbage you want there and it won't be instantiated until the BackupManager attempts to create it.

Answer (score -1):

To me it seems like there's a duplicate package being installed on the device. If I were you, I'd test:

- Has the package name been inadvertently been changed.
- Have you tried to clean the project, uninstall the app from your test device, re-build and re-installed it?

I know these questions may seem like Captain Obvious to you but I can't tell you how many times these two things have saved me.

Comment: The package name has not been changed.
I can not reproduce the error myself, it works well when I try it. The error message above is from a user which has downloaded my app from the Android Market and has uploaded an error report when the app crashed. So the message is from the Developer Console in Android Market.

Comment: Well, I can only assume that the user have downloaded it from Android Market. It might very well come from another location. It is a paid app and relatively popular around the file sharing sites. Maybe that can explain the appended "-2" at the end of the installation path? But can that "-2" be the reason to why the class is not found?
Say that the user did download my app from an illegal download site. Will the error reports in Android still go to my Developer Console in Android Market?